# Is my site compromised

Tags: hosting

Hello Great and experienced Stackoverflow coders, I just accessed my site using ftp and behold I saw a new folder  called ".well-known" in my root directory that is inside public_html and when I open the folder, I saw another folder called "Acme-Challenge". This is the drectory "/public_hml/.well-known/acme-challenge".

What amazed me is that the directory is empty. okay then I tried to access my bash command from "Putty", and the command said "bash: fork: cannot allocate memory" and since then my site appears with " 500 internal error".

Am I compromised.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your web host might have enabled LetsEncrypt SSL certificate on the server where your website is hosted. Let’s Encrypt is a free, automated, and open Certificate Authority. It automatically installs a signed, trusted, and secure SSL certificate on all domains hosted on the server.

While installing this certificate LetsEncrypt authenticates a domain name through protocol, called Automatic Certificate Management Environment (ACME) and domain validation. To verify the domain name being requested, LetsEncrypt CA issues one or more sets of challenges. And therefore, `well-known` and `acme-challenge` directories are created to place validation files in them. These directories are safe and should not be removed. You may find more details here, ... https://letsencrypt.org/how-it-works/